# Should there be a comma before "accompanied by"?

Tags: punctuation, commas

> Such reactions may appear as edema or inflammation at the injection site or cause a variety of manifestations elsewhere, such as redness of the skin, itching, conjunctivitis, rhinitis, swelling of the face (angioedema), the upper or (and) lower lip, cheeks, vocal cords, pharynx **accompanied by** difficulty of breathing or swallowing, urticaria, severe dyspnea, which may progress to anaphylactic shock.

Should there be a comma before "accompanied by"?

The Russian original uses "with" instead of "accompanied by", but I thought that might mean like "pharynx with difficulties of breathing", so I used "accompanied".

I think that if there was a full stop after "swallowing", a comma would have been okay; but with the list continuing, it might be better without one.

Comment: It's a parenthetic in this context, but more commas would be confusing. So I'd use parentheses: "... the pharynx (accompanied by difficulty breathing or swallowing), urticaria..."

Comment: The sub-list is a list of swelling sites, governed by **of**.

Comment: No, a semicolon before **pharynx** would not do, since **pharynx** is one of the objects of preposition **of** in **swelling of...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comma after "pharynx" is not necessary is "accompanied" is not part of the list of body parts, but usually there would be an "or" before "pharynx"

> swelling of the face (angioedema), the upper or (and) lower lip, cheeks, vocal cords, **or** pharynx accompanied by difficulty of